# Passing variables back from a ViewController to a previous one, but variables not updating?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have two view controllers which I am interested in passing variables from one view controller to the next in a backwards manner. To achieve this I used a protocol, however, the variable in the first view controller are not updating when going back from view controller two to view controller one:

Below is my code for the first view controller:

```
    import UIKit

    class BlueBookUniversalBeamsVC: UIViewController {

        var lastSelectedTableRowByTheUser: Int = 0

        var lastSelectedTableSectionByTheUser: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()

            print(lastSelectedTableRowByTheUser)

            print(lastSelectedTableSectionByTheUser)

     }

 }

    extension BlueBookUniversalBeamsVC: ProtocolToPassDataBackwardsFromDataSummaryVcToPreviousVc {

        func dataToBePassedUsingProtocol(passedSelectedTableSectionNumberFromPreviousVc: Int, passedSelectedTableRowNumberFromPreviousVc: Int) {

            self.lastSelectedTableRowByTheUser = passedSelectedTableRowNumberFromPreviousVc

            self.lastSelectedTableSectionByTheUser = passedSelectedTableSectionNumberFromPreviousVc

            print("Last selected row passed back from SummaryVC is equal to \(passedSelectedTableRowNumberFromPreviousVc)")

            print("Last selected section passed back from SummaryVC is equal to \(passedSelectedTableSectionNumberFromPreviousVc)")

    }
```

Below is my code inside the second view controllerL

```
import UIKit

class BlueBookUniversalBeamDataSummaryVC: UIViewController {

   var delegate: ProtocolToPassDataBackwardsFromDataSummaryVcToPreviousVc?

   @objc func navigationBarLeftButtonPressed(sender : UIButton) {

        let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let previousViewControllerToGoTo = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BlueBookUniversalBeamsVC")

        if delegate != nil {

            delegate?.dataToBePassedUsingProtocol(passedSelectedTableSectionNumberFromPreviousVc: self.selectedTableSectionNumberFromPreviousViewController, passedSelectedTableRowNumberFromPreviousVc: self.selectedTableRowNumberFromPreviousViewController)

        }

        self.present(previousViewControllerToGoTo, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

The weird thing is that in Xcode console when I go back from VC2 to VC1, inside the protocol function extension in VC1 I can see the values being printed correctly. However, when the values get printed from inside `viewDidLoad()` both of them are showing as 0. Any idea why this is happening, is there something I am missing out here?

Comment: Unrelated, the `if delegate != nil { ... }` is not needed. The optional chaining of `delegate?.dataToBePassedUsingProtocol(...)` already gracefully tests to see if the delegate is `nil` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second view controller is instantiating a new instance of the first view controller rather than using the instance that was already there. The second view controller shouldn’t `present` the first view controller again, but rather `dismiss` (or `pop`) back to it, depending upon the first presented or pushed to it.

By the way, the `delegate` property of the second view controller that points back to the first one should be a `weak` property. You never want a child object maintaining a strong reference to a parent object. Besides, delegates are almost always weak...

Comment: Thank you so much for your excellent and precise reply that sorted out my problem :)